# Can R.string. be used in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When I build/run my app, "2131165360" appears in the list view position instead of "LegKick Block 1". Why does this happen when i enter this code?

```
arrayList.add(String.valueOf(R.string.legkick_block1));
```

I could solve my problem by doing this but I'd rather grab the value of the string rather than hard-coding it:

```
 arrayList.add("LegKick Block 1");
```

Is there an approach to put a value of a string in a array list?

Comment: Maybe: because "doesn't work" ... is not a helpful description of your problem. Please turn to the help center to understand how to write up such "not working" questions.

Comment: you can make an array of string in R.string file also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list.add(getString(R.string.legkick_block1));`

```
R.string.any_string
```

returns a integer value to resource, you need to use `getResource().getString(R.string.any_string)`
Or simply `getString(R.string.any_string)` which returns the string object mapped to the integer resource which you can add in list

Comment: Awesome, thank you Nishant Pardamwar! GhostCat, could you kindly explain? Or is it a big secret?

Answer (score 1):

Because R.string returns an integer, it cannot be used(alone) as a String value. Instead, do this:

```
getString(R.string.legkick_block1)
```

It retrieves the String value of(in this case) `legkick_block1`

Note: You have to reference an activity for it to work. Meaning it has to be used inside an Activity or referencing one.